# dispaly error message with out alert box using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

i want to display error message without alert box by using javascript.

i have tried with code.

```
function validatetextbox() {
var txtuname = document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').value;
if(txtuname=="") {
    document.getElementById("text_uname").innerHTML= "Enter Username"; } }
```

but it is not working, please give some suggestions

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').innerHTML= "Enter Username"; } }`.

Comment: Please be careful about formatting..

Comment: It is not worling. im using ajax updatepanel.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>')` instead of `document.getElementById("text_uname")`

Complete function

```
function validatetextbox() {
    var txtuname = document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').value;
    if (txtuname == "") {
        document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Enter Username";
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working, im using ajax updatepanel. does any went wrong

Answer (score 0):

try to cache dom, and set innerHTML

```
function validatetextbox() {

    var inputEl = document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>'),
       txtuname = inputEl.value;

    if ( txtuname == "" ) {
        inputEl.innerHTML = "Enter Username";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to show alert in txt_uname .. then you should do like this:

```
function test(){
    var txtuname =document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').value;

     if(txtuname == "") {
       document.getElementById('<%=txt_uname.ClientID %>').value= "Enter Username";
         } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function test()
{ 
var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
var txtuname= row.cells[your cell number].childNodes[your node number].innerHTML;
if(txtuname=="")
{
txtuname="enter username";
}
```

}